# Div Disappears when given Fixed Position

Tags: html, css-position, fixed

I am currently working on a website at [www.thejasonsanders.com](http://www.thejasonsanders.com) and whenever I try to give a div a fixed position in any of the sections aside from the first one ("Homepage"), the div disappears. I have tried everything I can think of to correct the issue and nothing seems to resolve it. So, I am turning to what is probably my number one resource in these types of matters!

I am currently testing an image in the "Portfolio" section under the divs "Portdiv" and Portdiv2" with the same styling as the main logo image. The main logo image is in the homepage section with fixed positioning and it is displaying correctly. Again, it is only when an image is placed in one of the other sections that things start acting weird. Can anyone please help me figure out what is going on?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a div is given a fixed position and it's outside of the viewport basically doesn't exist. I think that's the problem you're facing. [Here's a quick demo](http://jsbin.com/umedig/2/edit). Notice when you make your browser window taller and shorter the `<img>`s disappear. You probably want to use `position: absolute`? Sorry If I'm way off.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, Bill! Your answer actually makes a lot of sense, and it opened my eyes to the fact that I was thinking about my problem in the wrong way. I appreciate you taking the time to explain that to me. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, it seems to be a bug that occurs when there is too much going on inside the page, I was able to fix it by adding the following transform code to the fixed position element, (`transform: translateZ(0);-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`) that forces the browser to use hardware acceleration to access the device’s graphical processing unit (GPU) to make pixels fly. Web applications, on the other hand, run in the context of the browser, which lets the software do most (if not all) of the rendering, resulting in less horsepower for transitions. But the Web has been catching up, and most browser vendors now provide graphical hardware acceleration by means of particular CSS rules.

Using -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); will kick the GPU into action for the CSS transitions, making them smoother (higher FPS).

**Note:** translate3d(0,0,0) does nothing in terms of what you see. it moves the object by 0px in x,y and z axis. It's only a technique to force the hardware acceleration.

```
#fixed-element {
    position: fixed;
    /* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* seems to do the same in Safari Family of Browsers*/
}
```